# SQL Query Start Time & Finish Time using Exact Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of data and each row/record has a **Start Date and Time** and a **Finish Date & Time** as shown below.

[image]

I want to be able to run a query which will display the users who were online at specific time, lets say **2017-04-26 12:47**.

Going off the below data that would display the records below.

[image]

I understand how to find the records between the **Start Time** and **Finish Time** like below but ideally I would just like to find results by who was online at specific time rather than **Start Time >=** and **Finish Time <=**.

Does that make sense?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT [UserLogID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[FinishTime]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [FOO].[dbo].[BAR]
  where StartTime <= '2017-04-26 12:50:00' and FinishTime >= '2017-04-26 12:55:00'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Sqlite? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: MS SQL ideally, I've used images because StackOverflow does not allow for tables. I'll ensure future posts use formatted text though.

Comment: SO support table, just have to add 4 spaces for each line or use control-k to format as code. Use this site to get a nice looking table https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: I never knew that existed, its now bookmarked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted `>= <=`:

```
WHERE  StartTime <= '2017-04-26 12:50:00' 
  AND FinishTime >= '2017-04-26 12:50:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: If that wasnt the problem I dont understand the question :( Also you use two diferent time 12:50 and 12:55 You want compare with a range or with a single time?

Comment: This is an example of how I currently work however I'm still required to separate the wheat from the chaff. I would ideally like to be able to just query by one point in time rather than a range.

Comment: Then my answer should work. Let me know if have other question

Comment: I've just tested and thats perfect, thank you very much.